# How do i remove this from logged in users?

Tags: customization

This is what normal logged in users see in the left corner on the site.
I want to remove the WP logo and WP logo's functions

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wisq.png

Comment: You just want to remove the logo? Or the dropdown too, that comes with it?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need to remove that WordPress logo and dropdown under it from your WordPress backend.

For that, you can add this code in your theme's functions.php

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style(){
    wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.1' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style');
```

Also create a CSS file on the root of your active theme folder, i.e. `admin-style.css`
And the content of this CSS file will be:

```
#wp-admin-bar-wp-logo {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: can i also remove the "Pixel Craft" button?

Comment: @HyperOne That is not a part of default WordPress installation. That is coming from some plugin I guess. Can't give you a solution without looking at it.

Comment: ok, thanks for helping but can i ask one more question. How can i remove this: https://ibb.co/DghvKxF

Comment: sorry new link: https://ibb.co/X8Frrrf

Comment: Well that's the theme credits and every theme has a different way to embed it. So I am not sure how to do it without looking at it.

Comment: Also do let me know if the previous answer helps to solve your query?

Comment: yes previous answer helped, thank you!

Comment: What can i do to remove the theme credits?

Comment: Well I need to check the backend of the website to give solution for that. Please mark the question as solved by accepting the answer to previous to question.